# Find and replace inside string based on pattern and exception cases

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I have a JSON string that returns some key value pairs but if the value is numeric it doesn't enclose it with double quotes so my JSON parsing isn't working for those cases.

My idea is to manipulate the string by searching and replacing any occurrences where it finds `:` with `:"` except when the : is followed by an open curly brace {

I would also need to close the double quotes at the end so I need to find a way to look for any 0-9 followed by a comma and replace that comma with `",`

I am thinking I need SED to search/replace but I am very new to SED and RegEx so not sure how to start especially omitting places where it finds `"{` and using RegEx to find `[0-9],`

Sample JSON string looks like:

```
{"data":{"project":{"issue":{"session":{"id":"625fdv6b95e232f08d6cy2686624f315","createdAt":1539849060000,"buildVersionId":"75492373","sdk":{"display":"1.11.1"},"os":{"platform":"unknown","modified":false},"memory":{"free":853000192,"used":1896611840},"storage":{"free":241791528960,"used":14197940224},"device":{"architecture":"arm64","manufacturer":"Samsung"}}}}}}
```

Desired finished JSON after the change would look like:

```
{"data":{"project":{"issue":{"session":{"id":"625fdv6b95e232f08d6cy2686624f315","createdAt":"1539849060000","buildVersionId":"75492373","sdk":{"display":"1.11.1"},"os":{"platform":"unknown","modified":false},"memory":{"free":"853000192","used":"1896611840"},"storage":{"free":"241791528960","used":"14197940224"},"device":{"architecture":"arm64","manufacturer":"Samsung"}}}}}}
```

pretty much the same thing but every number now has double quotes around it.

Comment: I see [some evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15368231/4957508) that JSON numbers should not be quoted.

Comment: Jeff, yes, I understand numbers won't be numeric anymore and will be considered strings but that won't affect what my end result will be so it doesn't matter for me.  I won't be sending this edited string to anything else for processing.  It's only used to parse and extract data out of it.  Thanks

Comment: What JSON parser are you using to extract data from the document?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not using any parser, that's the problem.  I'd love to use jq but I'm working in an environment where jq is not installed and it's hard to get it installed.  I'm basically doing what I put in my answer below.  grepping for the correct key and trimming the value received.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and instead of modifying the JSON data, I modified my grepping for numeric values not to look for the double quotes like so:

```
buildVersionId=`echo $jsonData | grep -m1 -oP '"buildVersionId"\s*:\s*\K[^"]+"'`
```

then I remove the last 2 characters ( `,"` ) from the end to get the actual number only:

```
buildVersionId=${buildVersionId::${#buildVersionId}-2}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed 's/:\([0-9]*\)\([,}]\)/:"\1"\2/g' inp >out
```

- `s/:\([0-9]*\)\([,}]\)` - search for `:` followed by digits, followed by either `,` or `}`.  Place the digits into capture \1, the `,` or `}` into \2.
- `/:"\1"\2/g` - replace with `:"` followed by capture \1 (the digits), followed by `"`, followed by capture \2 (the original suffix character)

Example

```
$ cat inp
{"data":{"project":{"issue":{"session":{"id":"625fdv6b95e232f08d6cy2686624f315","createdAt":1539849060000,"buildVersionId":"75492373","sdk":{"display":"1.11.1"},"os":{"platform":"unknown","modified":false},"memory":{"free":853000192,"used":1896611840},"storage":{"free":241791528960,"used":14197940224},"device":{"architecture":"arm64","manufacturer":"Samsung"}}}}}}
$ sed 's/:\([0-9]*\)\([,}]\)/:"\1"\2/g' inp >out
$ cat desired
{"data":{"project":{"issue":{"session":{"id":"625fdv6b95e232f08d6cy2686624f315","createdAt":"1539849060000","buildVersionId":"75492373","sdk":{"display":"1.11.1"},"os":{"platform":"unknown","modified":false},"memory":{"free":"853000192","used":"1896611840"},"storage":{"free":"241791528960","used":"14197940224"},"device":{"architecture":"arm64","manufacturer":"Samsung"}}}}}}
$ diff out desired
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
jq -c '(.. | select(numbers)) |= tostring' file >newfile
```

This `jq` command converts all numbers in your JSON document into strings, regardless of where in the document the numbers are found.

The output is written in "compact" form to the file `newfile`.

In case you, for whatever reason, have ended up with your JSON document in a shell variable, `data`, then instead use

```bash
jq -c -n --argjson d "$data" '$d | (.. | select(numbers)) |= tostring' >newfile
```